# Cordova plugins undefined when tested on device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am using Phonegap with ngCordova and AngularJS. I am trying to use the following plugin ([PhoneGap-Image-Resizer](https://github.com/RaananW/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer/)) to help me save some media to the device. My issue is that my plugin is giving me the following error:

[phonegap] [console.error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$window.imageResizer.getImageSize')

This only happens when i check the app on my device, when I run it locally through localhost:3000 I do not get the error. I get similar results when running a console log after the DeviceReady call. In the browser it is fine, where on the device it is undefined.

After a lot of research I have seen a few check the cordova.js file is being referenced in my index.html, which as you can see below it is:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
</head>

<body class="app-container">
    <div class="app">
      <div ng-app="MyApp" class="ui-view-container">
        <ui-view class="main-view">
        <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="my App" class="loading-logo"/>
        </ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-foundation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-modules/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-modules/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my partial

```
<div class="row collapse expanded text-center camera">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns end">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="250" width="375"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="small-12 columns">
    <h2>Image of canvas</h2>
            <img id="CanvasImage" alt="text" /> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <a class="button expanded" ng-click="camera()">Camera</a>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <a class="button expanded" ng-click="savecanvas()">savecanvas</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('CameraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $rootScope, $location, $window, starFactory) {

        $scope.savecanvas = function() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                var theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var CanvasImage = document.getElementById('CanvasImage');
                CanvasImage.src = theCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                $window.imageResizer.storeImage(
                    function(data) { console.log('It worked!');}, 
                    function (error) {console.log("Error : \r\n" + error);}, 
                    theCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
                    {imageDataType: ImageResizer.IMAGE_DATA_TYPE_BASE64,format: ImageResizer.FORMAT_JPG}
                );

            }, false);
        };


    });
```

If anyone could please help me, understand why when i am on my device the plugins are undefined, when they work fine on the browser I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very tricky one to get my head around but we have finally got an answer. Phonegap uses Hydration, which is a way to update your application without having to reinstall it each time. Turns out there is a bug with Hydration in Phonegap 6.5.0 that means the cordova.js file is not loading properly. To solution to this is to Turn off Hydration. Once i turned that off, the plugins started to load on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I see you get the data URL from the canvas as a PNG but then try to store it as a jpg?

Maybe try this:

```
theCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
```

Instead of this:

```
theCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I studied about the plugin in the Git-hub. There in the Android quirks and howto's section, it is mentioned that the **The storeImage funtion will always store the image to the device's default external storage, under the given Directory and filename. the photoAlbum property will be ignored.** If this is the case, I think you need to have the external memory card in your mobile device.